# Reasons for hibernate sessions not being unbound from thread context

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, load-balancing, ajp

I'm relatively new to Hibernate technology and currently struggling with a strange issue I still can't resolve. We have an application which is load-balanced with 2 Tomcat installations and Apache 2.2 server (mod_proxy_ajp). From time to time (still have trouble with tracing this behavior) some ajp-threads after request processing are left with not-unbound hibernate session.
If that threads afterwards aren't used some amount of time (the time during which connection to database is getting idle) we end up with opened hibernate session through which communication with database isn't available anymore and hence exception occurs if a request eventually comes to the thread.

The question is: what possible reasons could lead to this behavior, what things should I check to make it more clear and maybe finally find a resolution?

By the way we also have the same application working without load-balancing in which the issue is not experienced.

Comment: Try to make thread dump when you encounter this situation again. Maybe those treads are stuck on something.

Comment: @talex The problem is that the issue repeats quate often and we couldn't dump failed threads all the time so it's important to find the causes. But now I don't know what direction to dig in.

Comment: You need to make dump only once then analyze it.

Comment: How do you connect to the database? Do you use a c3p0 pool? If this is the case could you share your `c3p0.properties` file?

Comment: @Aldian Connection pool is the one provided by tomcat.

Comment: @TonyStrych9 I think you don't understand what you are speaking about. Please share your hibernate configuration